# What is the sum of $\sum_{k=1}^∞ \left(\frac{\sqrt {k+1}-\sqrt{k}}{\sqrt {k^2+k}}\right)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

What is the sum of the series

$$\begin{align} \sum_{k=1}^∞  \left(\frac{\sqrt {k+1}-\sqrt{k}}{\sqrt {k^2+k}}\right)\end{align}$$

Answer (score 4):

Hint:
$$ \frac{\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k}}{\sqrt{k^2+k}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}$$
and so this is a telescoping series.

Comment: I have been looking for this decomposition of the series for an hour. :) Thanks for the help. In this case, the sum is 1, I believe. You are a genious.

Comment: Yes, that's right: the sum is $1$.